# How to correctly use NED-Trie without macro?

Tags: c++, trie

I'm trying to use [NED-Trie](http://www.nedprod.com/programs/portable/nedtries/), it only has a single header [file](https://github.com/ned14/nedtries/blob/master/nedtrie.h). 
How to use this library without using `NEDTRIE_*` macro? and iterate to get the key and the value from `iterator`? It seems there are no `first` and `second` property on the `trie_iterator`

```
#include <cstring>
#include "nedtrie.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
typedef nedtries::trie_map<string,double> MSD;
int main() {
  MSD m;
  m["test"] = 1234;
  m["yay"] = 2345;
  m["foo"] = 3456;
  m["bar"] = 4567;
  for(auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
     string key = it->first;
     double val = it->second; 
  } 
}
```

From the errors, it seems `trie_map` cannot be used with `std::string`?

```
In file included from nedtrie.cpp:2:
./deps/nedtrie.h:1813:20: error: no viable conversion from 'const std::basic_string<char>' to 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long')
            return r->key;
                   ^~~~~~
./deps/nedtrie.h:1625:14: note: in instantiation of member function 'nedtries::intern::findkeyfunct_t<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>,
      std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> >, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double> >::operator()' requested here
      return keyfunct_()(*v);
             ^
./deps/nedtrie.h:611:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'nedtries::intern::to_Ckeyfunct<nedtries::intern::findkeyfunct_t<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double,
      nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> >, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double> >, nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double,
      nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> > >' requested here
    size_t rkey=keyfunct(r), keybit, nodekey;
                ^
./deps/nedtrie.h:1898:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'nedtries::triefind<nedtries::trie_map_head<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>,
      std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> > >, nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> >, 24, &nedtries::intern::to_Ckeyfunct>' requested here
      return triefind<trie_map_head<mapvaluetype>, mapvaluetype, trie_fieldoffset, intern::to_Ckeyfunct<intern::findkeyfunct_t<keytype, type, mapvaluetype, keyfunct> > >(&triehead, (mapvaluetype *) buffer);
             ^
./deps/nedtrie.h:2069:50: note: in instantiation of member function 'nedtries::trie_map<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::allocator<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double,
      nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> > >, nedpolicy::nobblezeros, std::list<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>,
      double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> >, std::allocator<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> > > > >::triehead_find' requested here
      mapvaluetype *r=const_cast<mapvaluetype *>(triehead_find(key));
                                                 ^
nedtrie.cpp:9:8: note: in instantiation of member function 'nedtries::trie_map<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::allocator<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double,
      nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> > >, nedpolicy::nobblezeros, std::list<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>,
      double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> >, std::allocator<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> > > > >::operator[]' requested here
      m["test"] = 1234;
       ^
In file included from nedtrie.cpp:2:
./deps/nedtrie.h:1814:18: error: no viable conversion from 'std::basic_string<char>' to 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long')
          return keyfunct()(v);
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
./deps/nedtrie.h:1728:19: warning: unused variable 'ensure_trie_link_offset_is_bounded' [-Wunused-variable]
      static char ensure_trie_link_offset_is_bounded[trie_link_offset+sizeof(trie_link)<=sizeof(*this)];
                  ^
./deps/nedtrie.h:1939:76: note: in instantiation of member function 'nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> >::trie_maptype' requested here
      iterator it=iterator(this, stlcontainer::insert(stlcontainer::end(), std::move(val)));
                                                                           ^
./deps/nedtrie.h:2075:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'nedtries::trie_map<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::allocator<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double,
      nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> > >, nedpolicy::nobblezeros, std::list<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>,
      double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> >, std::allocator<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> > > > >::triehead_insert' requested
      here
        it=triehead_insert(key, std::move(type()));
           ^
nedtrie.cpp:9:8: note: in instantiation of member function 'nedtries::trie_map<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::allocator<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double,
      nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> > >, nedpolicy::nobblezeros, std::list<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>,
      double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> >, std::allocator<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> > > > >::operator[]' requested here
      m["test"] = 1234;
       ^
In file included from nedtrie.cpp:2:
./deps/nedtrie.h:1625:14: error: no viable conversion from 'std::basic_string<char>' to 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long')
      return keyfunct_()(*v);
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./deps/nedtrie.h:323:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'nedtries::intern::to_Ckeyfunct<nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double,
      nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> > >' requested here
    size_t rkey=keyfunct(r), keybit, nodekey;
                ^
./deps/nedtrie.h:1942:7: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'nedtries::trieinsert<nedtries::trie_map_head<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>,
      std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> > >, nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> >, 24, &nedtries::intern::to_Ckeyfunct>' requested here
      trieinsert<trie_map_head<mapvaluetype>, mapvaluetype, trie_fieldoffset, intern::to_Ckeyfunct<keyfunct> >(&triehead, const_cast<mapvaluetype *>(&(*it)));
      ^
./deps/nedtrie.h:2075:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'nedtries::trie_map<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::allocator<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double,
      nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> > >, nedpolicy::nobblezeros, std::list<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>,
      double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> >, std::allocator<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> > > > >::triehead_insert' requested
      here
        it=triehead_insert(key, std::move(type()));
           ^
nedtrie.cpp:9:8: note: in instantiation of member function 'nedtries::trie_map<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::allocator<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double,
      nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> > >, nedpolicy::nobblezeros, std::list<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>,
      double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> >, std::allocator<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> > > > >::operator[]' requested here
      m["test"] = 1234;
       ^
In file included from nedtrie.cpp:2:
./deps/nedtrie.h:1773:9: error: no matching function for call to 'trienext'
        trienext<trie_map_head<mapvaluetype>, mapvaluetype, mapvaluetype::trie_link_offset, intern::to_Ckeyfunct<typename mapvaluetype::trie_keyfunct_type> >(&parent->triehead, (mapvaluetype *)(&**this)) :
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
nedtrie.cpp:13:47: note: in instantiation of member function 'nedtries::trie_iterator<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::allocator<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double,
      nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> > >, nobblezeros, std::list<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>,
      std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> >, std::allocator<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> > > >,
      std::_List_iterator<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> > >, 1, nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double,
      nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> >, nedtries::trie_iterator<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>,
      std::allocator<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> > >, nobblezeros, std::list<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double,
      nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> >, std::allocator<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>,
      std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> > > >, std::_List_const_iterator<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> > >, 1,
      nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> >,
      nedtries::intern::noconstiteratortype<std::_List_const_iterator<nedtries::trie_maptype<std::basic_string<char>, double, nedtries::trie_maptype_keyfunct<std::basic_string<char>, double>, std::_List_iterator<unsigned long> > > > > >::operator++' requested
      here
      for(auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
                                              ^
./deps/nedtrie.h:1141:120: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'keyfunct'
  template<class trietype, class type, size_t fieldoffset, size_t (*keyfunct)(const type *RESTRICT)> DEBUGINLINE type *trienext(const trietype *RESTRICT head, const type *RESTRICT r)
                                                                                                                       ^
1 warning and 4 errors generated.
```

Comment: From its Readme.html "Its two primary disadvantages are that (i) it can only key upon a size_t (i.e. the size of a void *), so it cannot make use of an arbitrarily large key like a hash table can (though of course one could hash the large key into a size_t sized key)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am the author of nedtries. And you should have tagged this question with nedtries, and then I would have seen it much quicker.

You can't use anything but a size_t as a key in trie_map because the underlying C macro implementation only works with size_t keys. This is because it relies on bitscan CPU opcodes, and those take a size_t. You *could* use it with a double by casting it to a size_t if IEEE 754 were a stable binary format, but as it is not you cannot do this safely.

As the documentation says, pass any non-size_t keys through std::hash and check for collision after dereference. Regarding trie_map not providing first and second, well trie_map is a stonking pile of crap code. I do say in the docs not to use it. If you examine the source code, you'll see I do a large number of illegal and undefined behaviour things, all stuff you should avoid having in your code base. That said, as a rapid prototyper for "what if?" scenarios, specifically "will bitwise tries really help out my C++ code here?", it fits the bill.

The Boost C++ Libraries have seen some work done on a Trie STL container, most recently in GSoC 2013. Nothing production ready though. A shame, as C++ could really do with a proper trie STL container.

Niall

Comment: I'll just add that a concurrent_map implementation is best done using bitwise tries instead of red-black trees, and if I get a very good student for the concurrent hash tables GSoC project at https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/SoC2015 I'll have them implement concurrent_map as a Boost funded GSoC extension.

Comment: The following tags do not exist: [nedtrie] [nedtries].